# Firefox & AJAX Junk after document element

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

Im using a page fetch script to dynamically load a web page into a div. Heres the code. BTW Im using Firefox w/ Kubuntu

```
function fetch(URL, divId) {
        req = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    req.open("GET", URL);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

When i try to get it to load a page nothing happens and I get an error

> Error: junk after document element
>   Source File: file:///home/amnite/Stuff/MetalBraska/Shows/ContentRight.html
>   Line: 2, Column: 1
>   Source Code:
>   `<img src="Layout/HeaderDiv.jpg" width="250px" height="7px">`

Comment: Can you post the `responseText`? You may be able to retrieve it by outputting it somewhere before trying to set your DIV's `innerHTML`.

Comment: @David: Good idea. Not necessary. He has `req.status == 200` for a `file://` URL.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My answer is in sections

- The error
- But that does not even matter
- The real problem
- How someone could have found the cause/real problem
- A solution that includes error handling

### The error

The error is because it is trying to parse `ContentRight.html` as an XML file. XML files are strict, so any little thing like a missing `</img>` would cause a whole failure. In this case, there is more than one top level element. (in a normal HTML, there is only one top level element `<html>`). The second top level element is considered "Junk after document element". I am assuming that image is the second element that is causing the problem.

### But that does not even matter

But this is all beside the point. There is no reason for you to parse the XML in the first page. You just want the HTML. Right? My guess is, it is trying to parse the XML and store it to `responseXML`. Because of the error, `responseXML` is null. But you are using `responseText` so there should be no problem. (ignore the error)

### The real problem

All that and now I see the problem. You are requiring HTTP status 200 with `req.status == 200`. Since you are not using `http://` and you are instead using `file://`, there is no status code and no possibility of a server error `500` and little chance of detecting a not found `404`. So all you will get is `0`. A good practice when you get something like this is to add alert lines

### How someone could have found the cause/real problem

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(req.readyState)
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
}
```

would alert `1` `2` `3` `4` so you know `readyState` is 4. Then try

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(req.readyState == 4)
        alert(req.status)
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
}
```

You would get `0` and you would be closer to the problem.

### A solution that includes error handling

A good solution is

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0 && req.responseText)) {
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = '<b>Error. HTTP ' + req.status + '</b>'
    }
}
```

Because if status is 0, that **could** mean internet connection failure in which case `responseText` would be blank and then you would get `Error. HTTP 0`. If it was not blank, that would mean it was `file://` and it would work like a charm.

And of course a server-level error would give `Error. HTTP 500` or whatnot.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! Im new to the whole AJAX concept and I didnt even think about req.status causing this issue. I appreciate not only solving this issue for me but you gave alot more background info... Wish I could give you 20 thumbs up for going above and beyond...

Comment: I wish you could too :) haha. But seriously, I am glad I could be of help.

Comment: The solution to my problem will be very different from this one (because the situation is rather different) but the diagnosis that it's parsing my file as XML was spot on. One quick glance in Firebug confirmed what you said and tells me that I should be able to change the MIME type on my template files (.tmpl) and it should fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: change the MIME type of tmpl to plain/text