# Junk after document element. How to avoid XML parsing with ajax get (XMLHttpRequest) in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, text

[Firefox & AJAX Junk after document element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084978/firefox-ajax-junk-after-document-element)

I'm having pretty much the exact same problem as the above question, but for different reasons.

To reiterate the problem:

I have some html file:

```
<style> #hat { color: red; } </style>
<script> var hat = "fez"; </script>
```

Which I'm retreiving via vanilla ajax call:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', target, true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var response = request.responseText;
    } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    }
};

request.onerror = function() {
   // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

That is throwing an error in console:

`junk after document element`

I don't want the html file parsed at all.  I've tried searching for a non XML HttpRequest method, but JQuery is all I can find on the subject.  Perhaps there is something like a TextHttpRequest that just retrieves text without parsing it?  Or maybe there's a way to tell an XMLHttpRequest that parsing is unnecessary?

This all seems like it should be pretty obvious, but I just keep finding tutorials on ajax that use jquery.

[Here's a link to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29)

Comment: Code shown works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/8KtqVfOR9d0OWkAmgDgb?p=preview

Comment: The example you made is working on my end too.  I'll see if I can figure out what the problem is.  Still, do you know if it's still being parsed as XML?  The error isn't breaking my code at all, I just don't like having it parse things that don't need it.

Comment: It isn't valid xml to be able to parse it as an xml document. It is being treated as text string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you should need to do is add this line before .send():

```
request.responseType = 'text';
```

This worked for me:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// add a responseType here
request.responseType = 'text';

request.open('GET', target, true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        // Success!
        var response = request.responseText;
        document.body.innerText = response;
    } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
           alert('there was an error in the response.\n\n Error: ' + request.status);
    }
};

request.onerror = function() {
   // There was a connection error of some sort
   alert('there was an error in the request');
};

request.send();
```